# How to get daily Ua expert report

Tags: python, automation, client-server, plc, opc-ua

Good morning,
I want to create a daily report with the production parameter on a server that i remote monitor with UA expert (Unified automation). How can I do this? If this is not possible with ua expert, how can I do this? With a python opcua client?

Comment: Creating reports is not possible with the UaExpert because it is just a free OPC UA client for testing.  You can use another OPC UA Client or write your own depending on what you want your reports to look like.